# How can I speed up this double for loop?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, for-loop

This is code that multiply each column by column number.

like this.

```
[[1,1,1],
 [2,2,2],
 [1,2,3],
 ...]
```

=>

```
[[1,2,3],
 [2,4,6],
 [1,4,9],
 ...]
```

And I want to reduce the time it takes to run this code.
The time should be a half of this code's running time.
(now it is about 0.04 sec, but it should be about 0.02 sec!)

But, also it must still be "double for loop".
How can I speed up this with keeping the structure??

```
import numpy as np
import time
x = np.ones((10000,3), dtype = np.int32)
start_time = time.clock()
y1 = np.empty((10000,3), dtype = np.int32)
for a in range(10000):
    for b in range(3):
        y1[a,b] = x[a,b]*(b)
print(time.clock() - start_time)
```

Comment: Simply do : `x * np.arange(1,x.shape[1]+1)` to leverage `broadcasting`.

Comment: Why does it still have to be a "double for loop"? That's an artificial constraint; where does it come from? The natural solution is for-loop free.